# Bad git pull creates invalid remote tracking branch

Tags: git, git-pull, git-extensions, git-remote

In my workplace, we just moved to Git for revision control after more than 10 years of using Source Safe (yay!). I now have to support our engineers in their learning of the new tool. It is important to note that we are all using the GitExtensions UI under Windows.

A couple of colleagues did the following (from the UI):

- clone the central repository (**origin**)
- create a new local branch (**A**) based on the main **develop** branch
- create commits on the **A** branch
- while having that **A** branch still checked out, they (mistakenly) did a pull of the main **develop** branch into their **A** branch

Here is what the UI of GitExtensions looks like when we do a pull (I sadly cannot post screen grabs from work):

> Pull from: **origin**
>
> Local branch: **A**
>
> Remote branch: **develop**
>
> Merge option: **Merge remote branch into current branch**
>
> (Pull button is then pressed)

Here is what the command log of GitExtensions reveals it did for the pull:

```
git pull --progress "origin" +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/A
```

After that command, the users saw a new **origin/A** remote tracking branch appear in their history, while we confirmed no branch **A** is present on origin.

I looked at the git pull manual to try and understand what happened, but I still cannot understand if what we are seeing is a GitExtensions bug or an misunderstanding on our part of what git pull should do.

Anyone can help me figure out what is happening here?

Thanks in advance

#### Edit

I know that pulling the remote **develop** branch into the local **A** branch does not make sense and I know how to resolve the situation by deleting the remote tracking branch. What I really want is to understand the logic behind the **origin/A** remote tracking branch being created in the first place, since no **A** branch was ever present on origin.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say whether this is a GitExtensions bug or not.  In corporate environments, it's very unusual (almost always a mistake) to pull in anything other than the identically named remote branch, so I'm not surprised you got odd results.  (I'd say it's a mistake to *ever* use `git pull` due to its horrific design, but that's another story.)

The `+refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/origin/A` part is called a [refspec](http://progit.org/book/ch9-5.html) (reference specification).  It says to make the local destination [reference](http://progit.org/book/ch9-3.html) named `refs/remotes/origin/A` (abbreviated as `origin/A`) point to the same commit that the remote repository's `refs/heads/develop` reference (the `develop` branch in the remote repository) is currently pointing to.  The plus (`+`) at the beginning says to force the ref to match even if the destination ref can't be [fast-forwarded](http://progit.org/book/ch3-2.html) to the source ref.

Thus, the `pull` command you mention causes Git to:

1. figure out what commit the remote repository's `develop` branch is pointing to
2. download that commit and its ancestor commits from the remote repository (except for the stuff already in the local repository)
3. force the local `refs/remotes/origin/A` reference to point to that commit
4. merge that commit into whatever is currently checked out

Based on the UI mock-up you provided, this is not what I would have expected to happen.  I would have expected GitExtensions to run the following instead:

```
git pull --progress origin refs/heads/develop
```

By omitting the local ref name (the part after the colon), Git does the following:

1. figure out what commit the remote repository's `develop` branch is pointing to
2. download that commit and its ancestor commits from the remote repository (except for the stuff already in the local repository)
3. set the local `FETCH_HEAD` temporary reference to point to that commit
4. merge that commit into whatever is currently checked out

Notice the difference in step #3.

I'm not familiar with GitExtensions, but here's what I think GitExtensions is doing:  It is assuming that you want the given remote branch to be designated as the official upstream branch of the given local branch.  With that assumption, creating `origin/A` as a remote-tracking branch for the remote's `develop` branch makes a moderate amount of sense.  I'd be curious to know if GitExtensions also modifies the `remote.origin.fetch` or `branch.A.merge` configuration settings in `.git/config` to really make the designation official.  If so, it's poor user interface design.  If not, then it's probably a bug.

Comment: I reproduced the problematic sequence of steps on a test repository and validated that the .git/config file did not get modified at all by the command called by GitExtensions. I think it must be a bug too, but I wanted to properly understand the mechanics of what was going on. You explanation is perfectly clear, and exactly what I wanted to know. I'll file a bug with the GitExtensions team and see where it leads. Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain this to me!

Answer (score 1):

You can only pull a checked out branch. This is where your tracking got mixed up.

The easiest way to see what's going on is to take a look at the .git/conf file. You will see what branch is tracking what remote branch. You can fix this by either editing the file directly, or using the --set-upstream option of git branch.

I would recommend fetching, then inspecting where the remote taking branches are and then updating your local branches by either merging the changes in, or rebasing them. You can also reject the changes by resetting and force pushing.

Also, consider using the command line. You get history of commands and other benefits.

Comment: I agree with your comment about the command line, but while I get around pretty well with the command line, some of my co-workers won't. Some of them are not developers (technical writers), so we needed a simple UI for them. So basically, are you saying that GitExtensions should not have let me pull from local, non-tracking branch?

Comment: I just tried looking at .git/config file and did not see any reference to the origin/A remote tracking branch in there. On the other hand, there is an **A** file in refs/remotes/origin... Of course, I know I can just delete the remote tracking branch with `git branch -rd origin/A`, but what I wanted was to understand the logic behind that branch being created in the first place.

Comment: It's a remote branch reference. But in your case it's not being tracked.